# How to Publish Void prism EventAggregator event

Tags: c#, prism, eventaggregator

How can I Publish void Prism event using Event Aggregator?

There is no option like this.

```
public class AllDataLoaded : PubSubEvent<void>
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to publish an event with no parameter.  In that case just use

```
public class DailyQcAllDataLoaded : PubSubEvent
{

}
```

Comment: CS0305 Using the generic type PubSubEvent<TPayload> required 1 type arguments. You can't do.

Comment: Hello Brain.I studied prism from your videos.Very good videos on the Pluralsight.:-)

Comment: If you are using v6.3 yes you can.  See fixed item #755 https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes-6.3.0

Comment: You can even see it in the source code https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/PubSubEvent.cs#L10